# ImportJSON doesn't include nulls

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been using this script from Brad Jasper and Trevor Lohrbeer to get JSON data imported to google sheets.

https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs

I'm trying to analyze the data from keepa.com (handles amazon prices historical data).

The CSV object tree should have 32 nested objects or "branches" with data according to a particular category, if there is no info on a particular branch, the "null" value is given (image 1)

[image]

When importing that data to google sheets, the script gets rid of the nulls, giving back only the branches with data on them Branches (0 to 5,11,12,14 and 30 on this case), which messes up the data array.

I tried using the "noInherit" option to keep the nulls, but to no avail (see image 2):

[image: !(https://i.imgur.com/LRJkwFs.jpg)]

[Keepa API, look for CSV] https://keepa.com/#!discuss/t/product-object/116

I want to get the "null" rows displayed, is there a way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: I don't see the code/function where you set the data into the spreadsheet, but may be if you change data[row][column] = "" to --> data[row][column] = "null" in the "noInherit" option "if" .The remaining data part is achievable. Please provide the related code to set the data in the spreadsheet.

Comment: I said it at the beginning of my post ;) , the full code is at https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs and it's called as a function from google sheets.

Comment: I changed data[row][column] = "null" but that didn't work.